Resizing Windows Has Become Very Difficult
I'm not sure when it happened, but resizing windows has started requiring surgical precision with the mouse.  Getting the resize cursor to appear at the edge of a window takes several attempts, as if the "target zone" to make the resize cursor appear is maybe one cursor tall or wide.  Is there a place in System Settings where I can adjust this?

What are the mouse settings? When did you last do a restart (that from one who can have days of runtime... :) )

I remember seeing complaints like this. Maybe it is a bug in SkyLight, sometimes your cursor just don't appear in time properly, giving user the impression that more precision is required, while it is already possible to drag from there.

In lieu of improving your accuracy of hitting window corners or sides, there tons of tools out there that help you with Window Management, via Mouse and/or Keyboard. I've used Divvy for upwards of a decade now, and have taken note of others that I've heard of but never ditched Divvy for, mainly because I've paid for it and have it nicely set up. And still works on Sonoma. Here's some that I know of;

Divvy ($14 direct and Mac App Store) - https://mizage.com/divvy/
Lasso (€10 direct only) - https://thelasso.app
Moom ($10 direct and Mac App Store) - https://manytricks.com/moom/
Magnet ($5 Mac App Store) - https://magnet.crowdcafe.com
Mosaic (Part of SetApp Subscription) - https://setapp.com/apps/mosaic

You may also like AlternativeTo's list of alternatives ( https://alternativeto.net/software/divvy/?platform=mac ) that lists these and a bunch more I've never heard of.
